# How to detect that mime type is for executable file?

Tags: java, mime-types, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tika to detect the mime type of an input stream
and I was wondering if there's a ready method to detect that this file is an executable file, there's a big list of executable files mime types here:

http://www.file-extensions.org/filetype/extension/name/program-executable-files

and I was wondering about the best way to cover them all.

Answer (score 17):

Apache Tika's mime-types have a hierarchy. So, you don't need to check for all possible executable types, all you need to do is check if the detected type has a parent that's one of the handful of executable umbrella types

For Windows, the main one is `application/x-msdownload`. You might also want to check for `application/x-ms-installer` too

For Unix, the main one is `application/x-elf`, but you potentially also want to check for the scripting formats such as `application/x-sh`, `text/x-perl`, `text/x-python` etc.

As for how to go from a Mimetype in Tika to its parent, you'll want [this existing answer here - "Correct use of Apache Tika MediaType"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179355/correct-use-of-apache-tika-mediatype). (Note that you need to recurse, in case there are multiple levels between the detected mime type and the base executable parent type)

Answer (score 1):

for microsoft windows the mime type is `application/x-msdownload`.   look at this http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: ,i don't want to make lots of checks for the list of executable files mime types.