# getting different mime type for exe file in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get mime type of an exe file in PHP. It's returning `application/x-dosexec`. but the mime type of an exe file should be `application/x-msdownload`.

I am checking with a temporary file `name($file_tmp_name)`, using the code below:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo finfo_file($finfo, $file_tmp_name);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: `application/x-msdownload` is only used by the IE browser I believe possibly to show that it's an unsafe executable.  The mime type is `application/x-dosexec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`application/x-dosexec` is actually a subtype of `application/x-msdownload`, specifically having the `.exe` glob.

You don't need to check for all possible mime types, just check if it belongs to the parent executable mime type. See how it's done with mediatype [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179355/correct-use-of-apache-tika-mediatype).

Ref:
[Summary of application/x-dosexec from webarchive.org.uk](http://web.archive.org/web/20160629113130/http://www.webarchive.org.uk/interject/types/application/x-dosexec)